# I'm trying to create random object using arrays and class with random locations?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, processing

I'm trying to create a game using classes, in which objects move to random locations and use arrays in order to add up in a random amount. Can someone help me to code this better as it isn't working? I'm using the software "[Processing](https://processing.org/)" by the way.

#### My Code

**My Class**

```
*final color ALIEN_COLOR = color(30, 100, 0);
 PImage background;
 int x=0; //global variable background location
 Superhero hero1;
 Alien [] invader1 = new Alien[8];
 void setup(){

   size(800,400);
   background = loadImage("spaceB.jpg");
   background.resize(width,height);

   hero1 = new Superhero(10, height/2); 

   for(int i = 0; i < invader1.length; i++){
     invader1[i] = new Alien();
     invader1 = new Alien(width,300);
  }

  } // setup ends
   void draw ()
 {
   drawBackground();
   hero1.render();
   invader1.render();

   if(invader1.move() == false){
   invader1 =  new Alien(width, 500);
  }

  } // draw ends*
```

and object as:

```
  ***class Alien{
     int x;
     int y;

   Alien(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
   }

  void render(){
    fill(ALIEN_COLOR);
    rect(x, y, 50, 50);
   }

  boolean move(){
    x = x - 1;
    return (x >= 0);
  } 
 }***
```

The error messages that I received are:

- the constructor Alien() doesn't exist.
- mismatch, Defenders.Alien doesn't match Defenders.Alien[]

Comment: `invader1 = new Alien(width,300);` looks incorrect, Just a guess. I don't know much about `processing`.

Comment: same here `invader1 =  new Alien(width, 500);`. You seem to be taking an array and treating it like a single variable.

Comment: If this is not an assigment and you are doing this to learn, I would suggest you have a look at The Nature of Code. It is a free ebook that can help you learn processing while master other ideas. I use the book but I code using JavaFX instead of processing.

Comment: Your other problem is addressed in the given answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `invader1[i] = new Alien();` but you do not have no-arg constructor in `Alien` class. Declare a no-arg constructor in `Alien` class as follows to get rid of the issue:

```
Alien() {
    // Put here some initialization code if needed else leave it as it is
}
```

Comment: Isnt this similiar, ***class Alien{
          int x;
          int y;

        Alien(int x, int y){
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         }

Comment: No. `Alien()` is a no-arg constructor while `Alien(int x, int y)` is a constructor with two arguments.